# Does 'their' point to the people or the officials in this sentence

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Can someone clarify whether this sentence is talking of the people's morals or the officials morals? What is the terminology that explains it e.g. Clause/conjunction etc. I don't yet know the keywords to search for this issue.

> The people trust that the officials they have elected will hold steadfast to their morals, ideas, and ethical principles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of [pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronoun) involves an antecedent (sometimes postcedent) as well-explained in [Wikipedia]:

> The use of pronouns often involves [anaphora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphora_(linguistics)), where the meaning of the
>   pronoun is dependent on an antecedent. This applies especially to
>   third-person personal pronouns, and to relative pronouns.

In your example:

> The **people** trust that the officials **they** have elected will hold
>   steadfast to **their** morals, ideas, and ethical principles.

There are two ***plural*** antecedents, i.e. "people" and "officials". As there is no indication that the officials elected themselves, the bold pronoun "they" points to the "people". Therefore, the bold possessive "their" should point to the same antecedent. Otherwise, you should not use "their" in the sentence and it should be rephrased to:

> The **people** trust that the officials **they** have elected will hold
>   steadfast to the morals, ideas, and ethical principles ***of the people***.

Or:

> The **people** trust that the officials **they** have elected will hold
>   steadfast to ***the people's*** morals, ideas, and ethical principles.

It could help prevent the confusion caused by "they" and "their".

Comment: @cdevelop Glad I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is one of those nonsensical political patter-speak sentences. The way it is worded, it means exactly nothing (or, alternatively, it could mean absolutely anything, which is the same thing).

Technically, it is ambiguous. Theoretically, it could mean either. Stylistically, it is garbage.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. Seems lesser ambiguous.
The people trust that the officials they have elected will hold steadfast to the morals, ideas, and ethical principles the people believe in.

The people trust that the officials they have elected will hold steadfast to the morals, ideas, and ethical principles the officials believe in.

Comment: Hi Mirza, Welcome to EL&U, it's nice that you have given a great suggestion but you didn't answer the question. Had the user asked for an alternative, then it would have been fine. However, we expect people to answer the question directly. You could always add the suggestions after you have stated the answer :)